# Changing Scope of Quantifier Natural Deduction

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am struggling to find a syntactic transformation for this:

$∀x(Pa∨Rx)$ to $Pa∨∀x(Rx)$

Using the natural deduction system outlined in Volker Halbach's 'The Logic Manual' my strategy has so far been to derive the conclusion from $Pa$ and from $Rb$ as both could be discharged using the premise after eliminating the universal quantifier. My problem is that I cannot derive the conclusion from $Rb$. How would I go about proving this, if my strategy seems to fail?

Comment: You can eliminate disjunction from $Pa\lor\lnot Pa$. Alternatively, you can introduce negation to $\lnot(Pa\lor\forall x\,Rx)$.

Comment: @SMM I have tried the latter but I am unsure on where to introduce the negation. Every step that I tried did not help. How would $ Pa\lor\lnot Pa$ help?

Comment: I think this Kripke frame shows the statement is not valid in intuitionistic first-order logic, so some form of classical reasoning will be necessary: partial order is $0 \le 1$; $U(0) = \{ a \}, U(1) = \{ a, b \}$; $0 \Vdash Ra$; $1 \Vdash Ra$; $1 \Vdash Pa$.

Comment: This is one of those propositions that isn't true in an empty universe.  So you can check whatever your proof is, you are going to need to use at least 1 rule of inference that is invalid in an empty universe.

Comment: @DanielV I read the (implicit) assumption as being either that $a$ is a closed term of the language under consideration, or else that $a$ is a variable which is assumed to be in the universe as part of the extended context for the variant of natural deduction allowing for empty universes, or maybe some combination where $a$ is a term involving variables in the extended context.  In any of these cases, the universe is either provably non-empty, or assumed to be nonempty in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One proof can be:

1. $\forall x(Pa\lor Rx)$ - assumption
2. $Pa\lor\lnot Pa$ - TND
3. $\lceil$ $Pa$ - additional assumption
4. $\lfloor$ $Pa\lor\forall xRx$ - introduction of disjunction on 3.
5. $\lceil$ $\lnot Pa$ - additional assumption
6. $\mid$ $\lceil$ u - new variable
7. $\mid$ $\mid$ $Pa\lor Ru$ - elimination of $\forall$ from 1.
8. $\mid$ $\lfloor$ $Ru$ - disjunctive syllogism on 5. and 7.
9. $\mid$ $\forall xRx$ - introduction of $\forall$ on 6-8.
10. $\lfloor$ $Pa\lor\forall xRx$ - introduction of disjunction on 9.
11. $Pa\lor\forall xRx$ - elimination of disjunction from 2, 3-4. and 5-10.

Another proof is:

1. $\forall x(Pa\lor Rx)$ - assumption
2. $\lceil$ $\lnot(Pa\lor\forall xRx)$ - additional assumption
3. $\mid$ $\lnot Pa\land \lnot\forall xRx$ - De Morgan's law on 2.
4. $\mid$ $\lnot Pa$ - elimination of $\land$ from 3.
5. $\mid$ $\lnot \forall xRx$ - elimination of $\land$ from 3.
6. $\mid$ $\exists x\lnot Rx$ - De Morgan's law on 5.
7. $\mid$ $\lnot Rb$ - elimination of $\exists$ from 6.
8. $\mid$ $Pa\lor Rb$ - elimination of $\forall$ from 1.
9. $\mid$ $Rb$ - disjunctive syllogism on 4. and 8.
10. $\lfloor$ $\bot$ - elimination of $\lnot$ from 7. and 9.
11. $\lnot\lnot(Pa\lor\forall x Rx)$ - introduction of $\lnot$ on 2-10.
12. $Pa\lor\forall x Rx$ - elimination of $\lnot\lnot$ from 11.

Comment: 1st case: why use TND ? Start from 6 and use $\lor$-elim.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, I don't see it. How do you introduce $\forall$ in the second case? It seems to me that you need TND again?

Answer (score 1):

> Using the natural deduction system outlined in Volker Halbach's 'The Logic Manual' my strategy has so far been to derive the conclusion from $Pa$ and from $Rb$ as both could be discharged using the premise after eliminating the universal quantifier. My problem is that I cannot derive the conclusion from $Rb$. How would I go about proving this, if my strategy seems to fail?

I am not familiar with that text, but the basic principle is to use reduction to absurdity.

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\boxed{\boxed{\fitch{~1.~\forall x~(Pa\vee Rx)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{~~2.~\neg(Pa\vee \forall x~Rx)\hspace{6ex}\textsf{Assume}}{\fitch{~~3.~\boxed {\color{blue}b}\hspace{16ex}\textsf{Assume}}{~~4.~Pa\vee R\color{blue}b\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Universal Elimination (1)}\\\fitch{~~5.~Pa\hspace{14ex}\textsf{Assume}}{~~6.~Pa\vee\forall x~Rx\hspace{5ex}\textsf{Disjunction Introduction (5)}\\~~7.~\bot\hspace{15ex}\textsf{Negation Elimination (6,2)}\\~~8.~R\color{blue}b\hspace{13.5ex}\textsf{Explosion (7); }\textit{ex falso quodlibet}}\\\fitch{~~9.~R\color{blue}b\hspace{14ex}\textsf{Assume}}{}\\10.~R\color{blue}b\hspace{16ex}\textsf{Disjunction Elimination (4,5-8,9-9)}}\\11.~\forall x~Rx\hspace{15ex}\textsf{Universal Introduction (3-10)}\\12.~Pa\vee\forall x~Rx\hspace{9.5ex}\textsf{Disjunction Introduction (11)}\\13.~\bot\hspace{19.5ex}\textsf{Negation Elimination (12,2)}}\\14.~\neg\neg(Pa\vee\forall x~Rx)\hspace{7ex}\textsf{Negation Introduction (2-13)}\\15.~Pa\vee\forall x~Rx\hspace{12ex}\textsf{Double Negation Elimination (14)}}}}$

Answer (score 0):

Using the system outlined in Volker Halbach's book, perhaps a possible proof of $\forall x(Pa \lor Rx) \vdash Pa \lor \forall xRx$ could be, I think:

$
\def\ae\qquad\mathbf{\forall Elim}
\def\ai\qquad\mathbf{\forall Intro}
\def\be\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow Elim}
\def\bi\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow Intro}
\def\oe\qquad\mathbf{\lor Elim}
\def\oi\qquad\mathbf{\lor Intro}
\def\ne\qquad\mathbf{\neg Elim}
\def\ni\qquad\mathbf{\neg Intro}
$

$
\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{
    \dfrac{
      \dfrac{
        \dfrac{
          \dfrac{\forall x(Pa \lor Rx)}{Pa \lor Rb}\ae
            \dfrac{\dfrac{[Pa]}{Pa \lor \forall xRx}\quad [\lnot(Pa \lor \forall xRx)]}{Rb }\ne \quad [Rb]
            }{
              Rb
            }\oe
            }{
              \forall xRx
            }\ai
          }{
            Pa \lor \forall xRx
          }\oi \quad [\lnot(Pa \lor \forall xRx)]
        }{
    Pa \lor \forall xRx
}\ne
\end{equation}
$